# Code unable to reference to local directory

Tags: c#, filepath

The situation is like this:

I am modifying someone's code to download an image file from a shared path.  So the person hardcoded the piece of code to be `@"\\" + local_path`

Since the call is expected to go and download from the shared path `\\network\bla\bla\bla`, it is fine to get hardcode in this way.

Now my problem come in, I actually need to modify some other parts and test it out in playback mode before I deliver this for actual use. However, my work guideline is not to delete away the `@"\\"` appended. Because, without the `@"\\"` the path would not link to the share directory and this changed .dll could not be used for actual activity.

Yet with this, if I were to use playback, the file path will now be `\\C:\temp\Images`, which will be wrong. My problem now is, how to maintain the ability of the code to link to share path and at the same time create a path local so that the code can reference to.

Comment: @"\\" became @"\". I keyed in the double back slashes but I don't know how all appeared to be single slash in the end. :)

Comment: so basically to wrap up, I changed the local path node in the playback xml to localhost\C$\temp\Images. after the "\\" is appended, the full path spells "\\localhost\C$\temp\Images" and thus now is referring to the rigth directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UNC path `\\localhost\C$\` will access the drive C: on your local computer.

Comment: thanks for sharing this with me. now my problem solved. :) I really learn something new. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to simply provide a flag which indicates the type of path you want to create e.g.

```
public string BuildPath(bool isUnc, params string[] pathParts)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(pathParts);
    return isUnc ? @"\\" + path : path;
}
...
var uncPath = BuildPath(isUnc: true, "network", "bla", "bla", "bla");
var localPath = BuildPath(isUnc: false, @"C:\", "temp", "images");
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. I was not expected to do code changes in this class, so I did not try out your recommendation. However, this logic seem to be working for me. really appreciated